# Codefluent Entities and .net Identity

Tags: codefluent

Now that CodeFluent Entities blog has disappeared, and after the refurbishing of the SoftFluent site, there is no more documentation available for this framework?
How it's supposed to get information about, let me say, ASP.NET Identities, jwt, aspects, templates and all that valuable information at the blog?
And what about all those we have projects tied to this platform?

Comment: Deixem-ho. No paga la pena.

Comment: Documentation is available as a github Wiki here: https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeModelerDocumentation/wiki

Answer (score -1):

https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/ is still available.

The blog was discontinued because too many of its articles relate to obsolete technologies but were considered by some in the public as up to date view or as valid recommendations even in nowadays context not considering their publishing dates. In 2018 it generated too many support by itself and it was decided to put it as private and provide answers to customers through support for those having support licenses or through StackOverflow only.

SoftFluent supports existing customers through their support program if they have one ( fixes, VS2019 support, questions on their usage/code, link to specific blog article if accurate or with comments).

Existing licenses are still valid, including Free and Personal.

Specific question can still be answered through this StackOverflow channel by the community of its users and sometimes support.

Comment: That's what I thought. Removing public info to get more payed subscriptions. It seems a little bit against the wave of open source tools that moved even Microsoft into dot.net Core.

Comment: A humble suggestion: a good community of small, free-lance or volunteers is a must on programmers market to spread and maintain a great tool like CodeFluent Entities. And added value services for big companies is the deal.

Comment: Sooner or later an open source alternative will appear and the tool will be surpassed. Look carefully at TeamViewer-UltraViewer case.